# Get javascript variable value from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've declared a variable in the first **.click** function, but on my second **.click** I am trying to get the first variable value, but it's not been able to find it, due to it being in a different function.

How can I set a global variable or something where other functions can use the value too?

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var checked = 0;
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
        var checked = 1
        console.log('checked');
        console.log(checked);
    }
    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
        var checked = 0
        console.log('not checked');
        console.log(checked);
    }
});
$('#button-cart').click(function(){
    if(checked == 1){
        alert('can continue fine');
    } else if(checked == 0){
        alert('cannot continue');
    }
})
```

Error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: checked is not defined**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `checked` outside the functions - this makes it accessible on the global scope. Then remove the `var` statements inside the function, or you will create a new variable in the function scope. This code will work:

```
var checked = 0;
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
        checked = 1
        console.log('checked');
        console.log(checked);
    }
    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
        checked = 0
        console.log('not checked');
        console.log(checked);
    }
});
$('#button-cart').click(function(){
    if(checked == 1){
        alert('can continue fine');
    } else if(checked == 0){
        alert('cannot continue');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid polluting global scope, the best practice would be to declare the checked variable within a closure so that only your event handlers can access it.

```
(function() {
    var checked; // No one outside of this immediately invoked function can see the checked variable.
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        checked = 0;
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
            checked = 1
            console.log('checked');
            console.log(checked);
        }
        else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
            checked = 0
            console.log('not checked');
            console.log(checked);
        }
    });
    $('#button-cart').click(function(){
        if(checked == 1){
            alert('can continue fine');
        } else if(checked == 0){
            alert('cannot continue');
        }
    })
}());
```

This way, both your click handlers can see the `checked` variable but it can't be accessed by anyone else.

Comment: Unless of course that variable needs to be accessed from somewhere outside the closure.  To which the solution is probably to create a module that contains the event handlers, then exposes the `checked` variable as a property of that module.